# Differential equation and rest points

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, differential

It is given differential equation $x'=x^3-x\mu$, $x\in \mathbb R$  with parameter $\mu \in \mathbb R $.

**i)** Can initial value problem $x(0)=a$,$a \in \mathbb R$ be solved explicitly? Explain.

**ii)** Determine all rest points and their type? Make sketch in $(\mu,x)$ plane where on vertical lines rest points $\mu=const$ are represented and sketch their behavior with arrows.

---

i) I don't know. Can someone give me some hint?

ii) $f(x)=x^3-x\mu$

$f(x)=0$

$x_1=0,x_2=\mu,x_3=-\mu$

$f'(0)=-\mu<0 \mapsto$ attractive rest points

$f'(\mu)=3\mu^2-\mu>0 \mapsto $ repulsive rest points

$f'(-\mu)=3\mu^2-\mu>0 \mapsto$ repulsive rest points

Sketch idea:

[image]

Is this correct and if yes, how to add "arrows"?

P.S. *Repulsive/attractive* rest points isn't probably the best translation, but I didn't know how to translate it right. On german it is: "abstossend/anziehend Ruhelagen".

Comment: The usual English terms are "equilibrium point" or "critical point" or "stationary point", not "rest point"; "unstable" or "(asymptotically) stable" rather than "repulsive" or "attractive", although such a point is also an example of a "repeller" or an "attractor".

Answer (score 1):

i) If $\mu > 0$,

$$ x(t) = \frac{a \sqrt{\mu}}{\sqrt{a^2+(\mu-a^2) \exp(2 \mu t)}}$$

(I'll leave the cases $\mu=0$ and $\mu < 0$ to you).

ii) No. $x^3 - x \mu = x (x^2 - \mu) = x (x-\sqrt{\mu})(x+\sqrt{\mu})$.
So $x = 0$ or (if $\mu > 0$) $x = \pm \sqrt{\mu}$.